# Wrong Unicode mapping when exporting .docx to PDF with LibreOffice

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

When converting a .docx file to a PDF/A-1a file with *LibreOffice*, the file created is not compliant with the PDF/A-1a standard.

When I try to validate the file using Preflight in *Adobe Acrobat* the following error shows ups:

```
Text cannot be mapped to unicode (154 matches on 2 pages)
```

And when I copy text from the PDF in *Preview.app* all accented characters are missing or mess up.

From my research I understand that *LibreOffice* is not building the `/ToUnicode` mapping correctly for accented characters because those characters are built for more then one glyph and *LibreOffice* is just dealing with the first glyph. Ref: [Can't copy text from PDF exported from OOo](https://bz.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=59576)

Is there's a workaround? How can I convert .docx to valid PDF/A programmatically on Linux?

For info here's the command I use to convert the file:

```
unoconv -f pdf -eSelectPdfVersion=1 source-file.docx
```

This other command does not give a PDF/A compliant file as expected but it have the same Unicode mapping problem:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf source-file.docx
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is present with LibreOffice 5.2.3.3 that I was using. The problem is not present with LibreOffice 5.1.4.2 and 5.1.6.2.

So downgrading to 5.1.6.2 fix my problem.

I added more information to an existing bug report.